# Is there an analog of the router.beforeEach() method in Framework7 that is in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, html-framework-7

I want to check each time the router passes the user's token.
Is there a method in Frameworks7 similar to router.beforeEach() in Vue?

Comment: `routeChange` event [here in the docs](https://framework7.io/docs/view.html#router-instance-events) may help you. have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation there is the "routeChange" event.

You can find it in the docs:
https://framework7.io/docs/view.html#router-instance-events

Like the description says:

> Event will be fired on current route change

This should be the exact same thing then `router.beforeEach` in Vue.js.